# Arithmatic operations on java collection objects

Tags: java, collections

The programming question is

Given two numbers represented by two lists, write a function that returns sum list. The sum list is list representation of addition of two input numbers.

Input:
  First List: 5->6->3  // represents number 563
  Second List: 1->4->2 //  represents number 142
Output
  Resultant list: 7->0->5  // represents number 705

I have tried using collections but got stuck during addition of collection objects. Any suggestion please?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Listdemo{
public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedList<Integer> l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> l2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Scanner i1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter first list values:");
    while(i1.hasNextInt()){
         int i = i1.nextInt();
         l1.add(i);
        }
    Scanner i2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter second list values:");
    while(i2.hasNextInt()){
         int i = i2.nextInt();
         l2.add(i);
         }
    Iterator r1 = l1.iterator();
    Iterator r2 = l2.iterator();
    while(r1.hasNext() && r2.hasNext()){
         int j= r1.next() + r2.next();
         System.out.println(j);
         }
```

Comment: Are number of digits in both the numbers going to be same?

Comment: "got stuck during addition of collection objects" in what way? Can you briefly explain what the code you posted above is doing?

Comment: @YoungSpice what the above code does is a normal addition in which the nodes of list contain an individual digit of number.     ex:suppose if the  number is 201, node 1 contains 2, node 2 contains 0 and node 3 contains 1 in the list.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh yes.

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting to do is "Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic". Essentially, each element in your lists corresponds to a position in a base 10 number. Assuming both lists are the same length (have the same number of digits), you would want to add the corresponding digits and if there is a "carry" (9+5 has a carry of 4), you would add that to the next element in the list.

Comment: That is what i wanted to do but i dont know how to retrieve collection object as primitive and apply addition operation could you help me with the code.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot treat a Java collections object as a primitive. What you would probably want to do it define a method `add` that takes two linked lists as parameters. Then manually perform the addition within that method.

Comment: Thanks @Jack Billings could you type in that code for me coz I'm new to java just gone through basics

Comment: This might be helpful: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32954/adding-two-big-integers-represented-as-strings

Comment: I will say that this problem isn't exactly "easy" for someone just starting out with programming.